# Search post_like + search by taxonomy checkboxes in one loop

Tags: loops, search, wordpress

Im pretty new in WP so pls forgive me my ignorance im trying to learn.

So I have two Wp_Query (search by typeing in searchbar and search by taxonomy checkboxes) and I dont know how to mix them... If one works second dont and its a cricle.

```
<?php

    global $search_ingr;

    if(isset($search_ingr)) {
        global $loop;
    } else {

    $query_params = getQueryParams();
        if(isset($query_params['search'])) {
            $query_params['post_title_like'] = $query_params['search'];
            unset($query_params['search']);
        }
    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
        'numberposts' => 60,
        'posts_per_page' => 60,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'post_status' => 'publish'
        ));
    }
?>


<?php if(isset($search)): ?>
    <div class="search-matches"><h4>Wyniki wyszukiwania:</h4><hr></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if ($loop->have_posts()) :?>
<?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post (); ?>

    <span class="tooltip tooltip-effect-4">
    <span class="tooltip-item">
        <div class="product">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                <div class="product-thumbnail"><span class="helper"></span><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
                <div class="product-name"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            </a>
        </div>
    </span>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
    <span class="tooltip-content clearfix">
        <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        <span class="tooltip-text"><?php the_title(); ?></span>
    </span>
    </a>
    </span>

<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Pretty long peace of code, Im pasting it with loop as well and above that I have search box and taxonomy list.

Additionally when I remove this:

```
// $loop = new WP_Query(array(
    //  'numberposts' => 60,
    //  'posts_per_page' => 60,
    //  'orderby' => 'title',
    //  'order' => 'ASC',
    //  'post_type' => 'products',
    //  'post_status' => 'publish'
    //  ));
```

Both searches works great(but I cant control post order and number of posts).
Any help on that?

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to modify the wordpress loop would be like this. 
Try this instead of the first block of PHP on top:

```
<?php
    $search = get_query_var('s');
    $loop = new WP_Query(array(
        'numberposts' => 60,
        'posts_per_page' => 60,
        'orderby' => 'title',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'post_type' => 'products',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        's' => $search
    ));
?>
```

The potential problem is that you are using functions and parameters which aren't native to wordpress - getQueryParams() isn't a wordpress function and the WP_Query function doesn't accept a parameter with name 'post_title_like'. If this code works then you might be using some plugin for the search functionality in which case you would have to override the plugin behavior, not the default wordpress query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! Really appreciate youre help but it didnt resolve my problem.
I will try another way 
This piece of code work perfectly for both searches but I need to change number of posts above limit of 10(thats why I started to messing with this code):

```
<?php

    global $search_ingr;

    if(isset($search_ingr)) {
        global $loop;
    } else {

    $query_params = getQueryParams();
    if(isset($query_params['search'])) {
        $query_params['post_title_like'] = $query_params['search'];
        unset($query_params['search']);
        }

    $loop = new WP_Query($query_params);

    }

?>
```

And the getQueryParams() function:

```
function getQueryParams(){
    global $query_string;
    $parts = explode('&', $query_string);

    $return = array();
    foreach($parts as $part){
        $tmp = explode('=', $part);
        $return[$tmp[0]] = trim(urldecode($tmp[1]));
    }

    return $return;
}
```